# Extracting the Last Name from a list of Full Names using Python / Pandas and possibly Regular Expressions

Tags: python, string, list, pandas

I am wrangling with a dataset and I have ended up having a list of names of the following form:

```
s = ['DR. James Coffins',
 'Zacharias Pallefas',
 'Matthew Ebnel',
 'Ranzzith Redly',
 'GEORGE GEORGIADAKIS',
 'HARISH KUMARAN K',
 'Christiaan Kraanlen, CFA',
 'Mary K. Lein, CFA, COL',
'Alexandre Cegra,  CFA,  CAIA'
 'Anna Bely']
```

I must extract the last names and place them in a separate list (or column in a pandas dataframe).  However I am puzzled with the polymorphism of the Full Names and I am novice in Python.

A possible algorithm would be the following:

```
Loop through the elements of the list.  For each element:
split the element into subelements using spaces. Then:

a) If there are four or less subelements start from the beginning and 
examine the first four subelements.
a1) If the first subelement is larger than 2 letters then: If the 
second subelement is larger than one letter, return the second 
subelement. Otherwise, return the third subelement.
a2) if the first subelement is 2 letters then drop it and repeat 
step a1
```

Comment: What did you try? Seems pretty straight forward python string operations.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a smarter way and I think Sunitha offered one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about always grabbing the second element of each line after skipping words that contain `.` and not in a exlude list `['dr', 'mr', 'mrs', 'mrs', 'miss', 'prof']`

```
>>> exclude_tags = ['dr', 'mr', 'mrs', 'mrs', 'miss', 'prof']
>>> [[y for y in x.split() if '.' not in y and y.lower() not in exclude_tags][1].rstrip(',').capitalize() for x in s]
['Coffins', 'Pallefas', 'Ebnel', 'Redly', 'Georgiadakis', 'Kumaran', 'Kraanlen', 'Lein', 'Cegra']
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this question, keep in mind that it is impossible in general to perfectly extract a person's surname from their full name, and go read  [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Sunitha's solution will fail for anyone whose last name is composed of more than one token (van Gogh), has more than one last name (Gonzalez Ramirez), has a first name that has more than one token (Mary Jane Watson), chose to put their middle name in whatever system created this list, is from an Asian culture where the order of given name / surname is sometimes reversed, etc.